# Does the One-Handed skill increase the damage of bound weapons?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

If I upgrade my damage with perks in the One-Handed skill tree, does it also increase the damage of a conjured One-Handed sword?

Answer (score 4):

It seems they are confirmed to benefit from the One-Handed skill: http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/One-Handed (first sentence under the One-Handed Skill heading):

> The following are the confirmed weapons that benefit from this skill:
>
> Sword - Iron, Ancient Nordic, Steel, Imperial, Blades , Silver, Dwarven, Orcish, Falmer, Elven, Glass, Ebony, Daedric, **Bound Sword**.

So with that in mind, I would only assume the perk also applies to it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Your conjuration skill will increase when you create the sword but after that it's treated like a normal sword.